# Image Segmentation library in Java

Tags: java, image, image-segmentation

I am working on a project which consist of a procedure of "reading diagram by computer"
I will need to do image segmentation in order to identify the shapes and their locations in the image input. My professor said that I can use any public image segmentation library to do it.
Is there any good image segmentation library which can serve this purpose?

thanks a lot

Comment: What do you expect an "Image Segmentation Library" to do?

Comment: i expect the library to take in a image and tell me what shapes is inside the diagram and their locations(can be relative or absolute or other kind of locations)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JAVA for example these tools provide many algorithms for image segmentation:

**ImageJ**

http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/

**Fiji**

http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Fiji

**Rapidminer IMMI**

http://www.burgsys.com/image-mining

**Marvin Framework**

http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/

---

**COMPLEMENT**

Even being generic, I think it is possible to answer this question in some sense. Since this question is closed, I gonna complement @radim-burget answer for those people that get here looking for a simple example of image segmentation in Java.

Image Segmentation is an image processing task and is handled by most image processing frameworks. In the example below I'm using [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/).

**Algorithm to segment diagram elements:**

1. Load image and binarize
2. Apply morphological erosion to remove lines, texts, etc
3. Apply floodfill segmentation to get segments
4. Draw the segments in the original image.

**Input:**

[image]

**After Erosion:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Source Code:**

```
import static marvin.MarvinPluginCollection.*;

public class SegmentDiagram {

    public SegmentDiagram(){
        MarvinImage originalImage = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/diagram.png");
        MarvinImage image = originalImage.clone();
        MarvinImage binImage = MarvinColorModelConverter.rgbToBinary(image, 250);
        morphologicalErosion(binImage.clone(), binImage, MarvinMath.getTrueMatrix(5, 5));
        image = MarvinColorModelConverter.binaryToRgb(binImage);
        MarvinSegment[] segments = floodfillSegmentation(image);

        for(int i=1; i<segments.length; i++){
            MarvinSegment seg = segments[i];
            originalImage.drawRect(seg.x1, seg.y1, seg.width, seg.height, Color.red);
            originalImage.drawRect(seg.x1+1, seg.y1+1, seg.width, seg.height, Color.red);
        }
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(originalImage, "./res/diagram_segmented.png");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SegmentDiagram();
    }
}
```

The shape recognition is another topic, already discussed on Stack Overflow:

[2D Shape recognition algorithm - looking for guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148136/2d-shape-recognition-algorithm-looking-for-guidance)